# does not implement interface member IComponentConnector2

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I tried to create a new Windows universal app (UWP) but new project seems to be broken.

I use Visual studio 2015 RC (version 4.6.00076), .NET for Windows Store apps (4.5.1.0)

How did i do ? I used this simple way :

[image]

And next, i tried to build project without modifying nothing in project.
And i got this error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0535  'MainPage'
>   does not implement interface member 'IComponentConnector2.Connect(int,
>   object, object)'    D:\Windows
>   Phone\\\obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.g.cs 16

I didn't find solution on internet, but maybe it's a problem with .NET version or assembly missing...

Does someone had this error too ? And what to do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to "repair" my Visual Studio installation but nothing new happened.

So, i tried to remove Visual Studio and to install it again.

First time i made custom installation, so this time i made full installation.

And it seems to works good.

strange bug :s

Comment: Have the same problem here ... thats really frustrating. A new full installation will cost me about 2 hours. Is there another solution?

Comment: i know that installation is wasted time but i didn't find other solution, sorry.